# tsconfig not working with commonjs as mondule setting for node

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, koa, tsconfig

I was trying to compile my code from ts to js, with `tsconfig.json` like:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "CommonJS",
    "target": "ES2015",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "strict": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "strictNullChecks": true,
    "alwaysStrict": true,
    "noUnusedLocals": true,
    "noUnusedParameters": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "preserveConstEnums": true,
    "outDir": "./built",
    "noImplicitReturns": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "declaration": true
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*"]
}
```

and my index structure looks like:

```
├───config
└───src
    ├───routers
    └───service
```

after compilation, built folder looks messed up:

```
├───built
│   ├───config
│   └───src
│       ├───routers
│       └───service
├───config
└───src
    ├───routers
    └───service
```

`src` folder is included in `built` folder...
how should I solve this?

Comment: does the config folder have .ts files that are transpiled by the compiler?

Comment: @KocsisDávid there is `.json` file and it does get copied to built/config

Comment: That could be a problem. TS chooses the innermost folder that contains all input files as I understand. But there is an option `rootDir` to override it, but it gives an error for files that are outside `rootDir`.

Comment: Thanks for replying to me! I have already moved all my config files into src folder just in case...